# xml layout crashes on loading for android app

Tags: java, android, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxqYK.png)Hey guys I'm at the end of my Java 1 class working on my project. We are making a memory/concentration game. My issue is that when I click the easy button for the next activity the app crashes. I have tried using fragments and activities and just can't seem to get it right. I have also tried using the layout I need on my main activity just to see if I could get it to display. Even then it just crashes on startup of the app. Any help would be appreciated.

Startup Screen activity.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.memory;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;



public class MemoryActivity extends Activity {

private Button mEasy;
private Button mMedium;
private Button mHard;
private CheckBox mSilence;
public MediaPlayer player;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memory);


    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mkstartmusic);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();



    mEasy = (Button)findViewById(R.id.easy);
    mEasy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent easy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EasyGame.class);
            startActivity(easy);

        }
    });

    mMedium = (Button)findViewById(R.id.medium);
    mMedium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    mHard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hard);
    mHard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    mSilence = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.silence);
    mSilence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mSilence.isChecked()) {
                player.pause();
            } else if(mSilence.isChecked() == false) {
                player.start();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player != null){
        player.stop();
        if (isFinishing()){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_memory, menu);
    return true;


}

}
```

Second Activity (Easy option)

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.memory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class EasyGame extends Activity {

private ImageButton buttOne;
private ImageButton buttTwo;
private ImageButton buttThree;
private ImageButton buttFour;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);

    buttOne = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
    buttOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    buttTwo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton02);
    buttTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    buttThree = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton03);
    buttThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    buttFour = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton04);
    buttFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_easy, menu);
    return true;



}
}
```

This is the layout for the Easy option

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/easyback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/easyback"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
    android:maxWidth="25dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dragonemb" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
    android:maxWidth="25dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dragonemb" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
    android:maxWidth="25dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dragonemb" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
    android:maxWidth="25dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dragonemb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `App crashes` Means everyone searches for crash log. No-one will review codes. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: to find crashes , please update you logcat.

Comment: OK, I added it. The amount of info was to big for screen shot let me know if you can see what you guys nee.

Comment: Have you tried `Intent easy = new Intent(MemoryActivity.this, EasyGame.class);` ?

Comment: try the above one and change your Button variable in to imagebutton.

Comment: you take ImageButton in your xml and in your you take Button in your activity.that's why ur app is crash

Comment: alright so I changed the argument in the Intent and changed the buttons to ImageButtons, but it still crashes. Also added the Activity back into the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK It's not the full crash log you posted but at the top of it I saw `roidManifest.xml?`. And It's sure that you didn't defined your `EasyGame` Activity in your `androidmanifest.xml` so add this line inside `application` tag,

```
<manifest package="com....." . . . >
     <application . . . >

         <activity 
           android:name=".EasyGame" 
           android:label="easygame">
        </activity>
         . . .
     </application> 
</manifest>
```

In addition you are trying to cast your `ImageButton` into `Button` consider fixing that as well.

Comment: I had that in before and took it out. I've added it back and took advise from comments above but its still crashing.

Comment: OK then post your full crash log by copying and pasting it... Do not post half screenshot.

Comment: I tried to copy/paste the LogCat but it won't let me. All I could do was post an updated screenshot of it.

Comment: May be some of your images are too large to decode... Reduce their size as much as you can by using external apps like Photoshop...

Comment: I just added them into the drawable xdhpi and now it works! All other images worked fine with being in the other drawable bitmaps guess the ones in this activity were different.

Answer (score 1):

Add code below to AndroidManfest

```
  <activity
        android:name=".EasyGame"
       />
```

Answer (score 1):

its simple just add this line to your `AndroidManifest`

```
<activity android:name="Activity"/>
```

The `logcat` did mentioned that you need to declare your activity within the Android Manifest which you didn't. please read the logcat carefully as it really helps to find what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had tried all of your guys suggestions which I had were part of the issue, the final issue turned out to that I needed to add my images to the drawable-xhdpi. Thanks for all your help.